# How to deduct salary if employee doesn't complete monthly hours?

Tags: sql-server

Monthly pay of an Employee is `50000` and total working hours in month are `248` i.e `8` hours a day. If employee works less than `248` hours there should be deduction from his/her pay and if he/she completes working hours there should be no deduction.
I have tried this query but it is deducting amount regardless employee have complete working hours.

```
SELECT 50000/248*248
```

Output I'm getting is `49848`. Maybe someone could help here.

Comment: Easier method would be 201.61 * montlyHours...

Comment: You have bad convertion i think SQL shown 50000/248 as INT

Comment: 5000 * 248 / 248

Comment: Hi think if you doesn't whant to use convertion (double or decimal) because float wasn't god way you have to use modulo : SELECT ((50000/248) * 248) + ((50000 % 248))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a variable for explanation, you can see how you can first divide to get the *hourly rate*, and then multiply by the *actual hours*. Be sure to use a `DECIMAL` so you don't result integer division.

```
DECLARE @ActualHours decimal(5,2) = 248.00

SELECT CAST((50000/248.00) * @ActualHours as DECIMAL(7,2))

SET @ActualHours = 240

SELECT CAST((50000/248.00) * @ActualHours as DECIMAL(7,2))
```

Comment: it's not be a very determinastic precision 49999.99994400

Comment: When you round that, or cast to the desired precision, you get the result you want @pascalsanchez... `select cast( 49999.99994400 as decimal(7,2))` making it deterministic

Comment: Yes it"s a real god way hi doesn't have other way :)

Answer (score 2):

The division is ok if you want to get the price per hour, but here you need to get the monthly salary multiplied for the percentage of hours

`SELECT 50000.00*248/248` will return the accurate value

Comment: You'll want to use 50000.00 so you don't get integer division, or 248.00, or whatever.